# Some examples of non trivial principal bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

> 1.Is there  a  nontrivial pricipal bundle $P(M,G)$, with $G$ connected, such that the total space $P$ admit a foliation such that each leaf is  diffeomorphic to $M$(Not necessarily via projection $\pi$)?
>
> 2.Is there a nontrivial principal fiber bundle $P(M,G)$ such that for every  k dimensional integrable distribution $V$ on $M$, there is a $k$ dimensional integrable distribution $V'$ on the total space $P$ such that $D \pi(V')=V$?

Comment: For part 1 take a nontrivial principal bundle with a flat connection whose holonomy is objective. For instance the flat SL(2,R) bundle over a hyperbolic surface, with holonomy given by the uniformizing representation.

Comment: For 1): any non-trivial bundle of $G$ over $G$?

Comment: Here is an example of Thomas Rot's suggestion.  Begin with the Hopf fibration, $\mathbb{S}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{S}^3 \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$.  The basic invariant of this $\mathbb{S}^1$-principal bundle is its first Chern class, which is a generator of $H^2(\mathbb{S}^2,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Let $f:\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ be a continuous map of positive topological degree, e.g., the standard $2$-to-$1$ map obtained by the involution $(x,y) \sim (-x,-y)$ with respect to the standard group structure on $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$ . . .

Comment: . . . The pullback to $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$ of the nontrivial $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{S}^2$ has first Chern class that is nonzero.  Now, turn this into a principal $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$-bundle via the standard group homomorphism $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$, $x\mapsto (x,0)$.  This $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$ is nontrivial, yet the fibers give a foliation as you request.

Comment: @JasonStarr How this group homorphism  $x\mapsto (x,1)$ define an action by $S^{1}\times S^{1}$?And why the resulting bundle is nontrivial?

Comment: @Misha  what do you mean by objective holonomy?

Comment: @JasonStarr are you sure that the pull back of hopf fibration to the 2-torus is a principal bundle and is non trivial? please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36444/sanity-check-is-every-t-principal-bundle-over-t-trivial

Comment: @ThomasRot  what is  a precise non-trivial principal bundle of G over G?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  Please look again at the link you included: that math.stackexchange question is only about the one-torus, not the two-torus.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: "How this group homomorphism $x\mapsto (x,1)$ define an action by $S^1\times S^1$"?"  I am afraid that I do not understand your question.  Are you asking what is the definition of the group homomorphism $q:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$?  Are you asking about the definition of the associated pushout principal $G$-bundle associated to a principal $H$-bundle and a group homomorphism $H\to G$?  For either of those questions, I recommend that you look this up in a reference.

Comment: Injective, I had an auto spell checker on.

Comment: I don't think I can improve much on @JasonStarr's answer.

Comment: @JasonStarr I am asking about pushout bundle. I think that if we have  an H-budle, then a group homomorphism H\to G gives us a G bundle. But you are considering the converse, G\to H? where is my mistake?

Comment: I consider the equivalent definition of bundles in terms of transition maps $g_{\alpha  \beta}$

Comment: @AliTaghavi: "where is my mistake?"  There are two group homomorphisms.  There is $q:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$, $x\mapsto (x,0)$.  For any $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle $E$ on a manifold $M$, there is an associated pushout $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$-bundle, $q_*E$.  Next there is a group homomorphism $r:\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$, $(x,y)\mapsto x$.  So for any $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$-bundle $F$, there is an associated $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle $r_*F$.  Of course $r_*(q_*E)$ equals $E$.  Thus, if $q_*E$ is trivial, then also $E$ is trivial.